# Why did I not get notified that my edit was declined?

Tags: discussion, editing

I recently asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/956565/using-aws-fargate-as-web-server), received a helpful answer to it, and edited the answer in an attempt to expand on it.

The answer itself was helpful and certainly answered my question, but adding more details never hurts, right?

Well, the edit must have been declined, because the whole "Your edits won't be visible until it's peer reviewed" text is not visible anymore - and my edit isn't either.

The problem: There was no notification of any kind that my edit was declined, no reasoning, nothing.

I would have really liked an explanation and maybe the chance to fix whatever I did incorrectly, but I didn't have it - my edits are lost.

Is that behaviour intentional? If so, should it be changed?

Answer (score 6):

Why the system only notifies users when their edits are approved and not when they are rejected is indeed puzzling. The reviewers who reject an edit do have to provide a reason for their rejection, either by choosing among a set of standard reasons or by typing in their own.

There is a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624/263194) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) with some more information.

There are two ways for you to learn about rejected edits. Next time you suggest an edit you will be told about the earlier rejection. Alternatively you can find the review as follows:

1. Go to [your profile page](https://serverfault.com/users/512694/markus-appel)
2. Click on the [Activity](https://serverfault.com/users/512694/markus-appel?tab=topactivity) tab on the top of the page.
3. Click on the [all actions](https://serverfault.com/users/512694/markus-appel?tab=activity) tab further down the page.
4. Click on the [suggestions](https://serverfault.com/users/512694/markus-appel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) tab a bit futher down.
5. Click on the [rejected edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/402336) you are interested in.

Comment: SE has very strange views on what users need to be notified about.

Answer (score 3):

Pulling up the [review](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/402336), it looks like one community member approved, but two others thought your edit was more appropriate as a comment. They voted "attempt to reply": "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

The review ends when two people have reviewed the suggested edit, and their choice (approve or reject) applies. The original person who wrote the post can also approve or reject it by themselves, without requiring any other reviewers, but that person didn't review the suggested edit.

Answer (score 0):

Everything for you - to keep you in bubble. If you really ask "why", here is why.

When an edit is rejected, it is better not to notify author, because he will come back soon and suggest an edit again.

This is a known problem when two users disagree with each other. Wikipedia has "page lock" because of this that is applied almost to any "mass" page, like countries. Because some people do edits for trolling and they **love** to repeat suggesting a *rejected* edit.

That is why obviously notifications are not sent when edit is rejected to avoid reminding of that edit which might have been very episodic and not very valuable. With such notifications, the author will become upset. See, bubble.